# Vba update user form based on text ID

Tags: excel, vba

Currently trying to apply another user form i found online to suit my needs.

The user form can be used to find and update values based on a numeric Id (SLNo) and it uses vlookup in order to find the information based on this ID, but in my dataset the ID will consist of both numeric and non-numeric values stored as text.

Trying to manipulate the form to read and update from a non-numeric ID such as changing the Dim for SLNo from integer to string, only helps the form read the values and i cannot update the values.

> run-time error 13 : mismatch

`debug -> rowselect = Me.cmbslno.Value`

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub cmbslno_Change()
Dim SLNo As Integer

If Me.cmbslno.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "SL No Can Not be Blank!!!", vbExclamation, "SL No"
Exit Sub
End If
SLNo = cmbslno.Value
On Error Resume Next
Me.txtregion.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("data").Range("A2:N1087"), 2, 0)
Me.txtmarket.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("data").Range("A2:N1087"), 3, 0)
Me.txtbNum.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("data").Range("A2:N1087"), 4, 0)
Me.txtcnum.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("data").Range("A2:N1087"), 5, 0)
Me.txtcity.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("data").Range("A2:N1087"), 6, 0)
Me.txtState.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("data").Range("A2:N1087"), 7, 0)
Me.txtpnum.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("data").Range("A2:N1087"), 8, 0)
Me.txtSdate.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("data").Range("A2:N1087"), 9, 0)
Me.txtInum.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("data").Range("A2:N1087"), 10, 0)
Me.txtIdate.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("data").Range("A2:N1087"), 11, 0)
Me.txtSamount.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("data").Range("A2:N1087"), 12, 0)
Me.txtsp.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("data").Range("A2:N1087"), 13, 0)
Me.txtSR.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("data").Range("A2:N1087"), 14, 0)

End Sub

Private Sub cmddelete_Click()
Sheets("Data").Select
Dim msg As String
Dim ans As String
If Me.cmbslno.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Sl No can not be Blank!!", vbExclamation, "SL No"
Exit Sub
End If
Dim rowselect As Double
rowselect = Me.cmbslno.Value
rowselect = rowselect + 1
Rows(rowselect).EntireRow.Delete
rowselect = rowselect - 1
msg = "Sl No " & rowselect & "  Successfilly Deleted...Continue?"
Unload Me
ans = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo, "Delete")
If ans = vbYes Then
UserForm1.Show
Else
Sheets("Data").Select
End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdupdate_Click()
If Me.cmbslno.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "SL No Can Not be Blank!!!", vbExclamation, "SL No"
Exit Sub
End If
SLNo = Me.cmbslno.Value
Sheets("data").Select
Dim rowselect As Double
Dim msg As String
Dim ans As String
rowselect = Me.cmbslno.Value
rowselect = rowselect + 1
Rows(rowselect).Select
Cells(rowselect, 2) = Me.txtregion.Value
Cells(rowselect, 3) = Me.txtmarket.Value
Cells(rowselect, 4) = Me.txtbNum.Value
Cells(rowselect, 5) = Me.txtcnum.Value
Cells(rowselect, 6) = Me.txtcity.Value
Cells(rowselect, 7) = Me.txtState.Value
Cells(rowselect, 8) = Me.txtpnum.Value
Cells(rowselect, 9) = Me.txtSdate.Value
Cells(rowselect, 10) = Me.txtInum.Value
Cells(rowselect, 11) = Me.txtIdate.Value
Cells(rowselect, 12) = Me.txtSamount.Value
Cells(rowselect, 13) = Me.txtsp.Value
Cells(rowselect, 14) = Me.txtSR.Value
rowselect = rowselect - 1
msg = "Sl No " & rowselect & "  Successfully Updated...Continue?"
Unload Me
ans = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo, "Update")
If ans = vbYes Then
UserForm1.Show
Else
Sheets("Data").Select
End If
End Sub
```

It was downloaded from this [Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Hk2CfkLV0ELVSiEUnYk9iiY2usJB0Ete)

I am really new to Vba, however i feel like if someone could alter this code to work it would be smooth sailing towards the end product i am looking for

Comment: You are getting `error 13` because the variable `rowselect` is of type `double`. In the code,  `SLNo` is assigned into `rowselect` which won't work if `SLNo` is a string.

Comment: Which I can't change due to `rowselect = rowselect + 1`. Any suggestions on how to build a user form to handle string as type when seraching and updating data based on non numeric ID.?

Comment: I haven't looked at your code, but the solution in the comments is easy if you use `CDbl(SLNo)` to convert the String to a Double.  I will add that rows can only be integers so declaring as Double is overkill and misleading.  Consider declaring as Long or Integer

Comment: It would have been better if you update the file you linked here with values of your needs. I don't think that solution is hard, but the time I (and everyone else, I believe) would like to spend here - is for looking for a solution, but not for trying to replicate your error. You don't need to update all those 2k rows of data, 10-20 rows of different options will be enough to find a solution.

Comment: Ok. Made a new post of it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823636/vba-update-user-form-based-on-text-id-v-2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vba update user form based on text ID v.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823636/vba-update-user-form-based-on-text-id-v-2)