# Vba update user form based on text ID v.2

Tags: excel, vba

Rewriting the question from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813873/vba-update-user-form-based-on-text-id?noredirect=1#comment105768234_59813873)

I am looking for a vba code to search and update data on each row for the excel example (see picture link) in user form.
The search and update should use column a "Serialno" as ID which is stored in text and result from search should update the columns for the row of the serialnumber.

I have already created a form to add data, but need another form for search and update.

form for adding data

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Me.TextBox1.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Add Serialno"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.TextBox3.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Add Weapon name"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.TextBox4.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Add dealer"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.TextBox5.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Add manufacturer"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.TextBox6.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Add weaponstype"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.TextBox7.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Add mechanism"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.TextBox8.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Add caliber"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.TextBox9.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Add pipelenght"
    Exit Sub
    End If

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
Dim n As Long

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("A:A"), Me.TextBox1.Value) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Dette serienummeret eksisterer allerede", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

n = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

sh.Unprotect "1234"

sh.Range("A" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox1
sh.Range("B" & n + 1).Value = Me.DTPicker1
sh.Range("C" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox3
sh.Range("D" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox4
sh.Range("E" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox5
sh.Range("F" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox6
sh.Range("G" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox7
sh.Range("H" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox8
sh.Range("I" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox9

Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox3.Value = ""
Me.TextBox4.Value = ""
Me.TextBox5.Value = ""
Me.TextBox6.Value = ""
Me.TextBox7.Value = ""
Me.TextBox8.Value = ""
Me.TextBox9.Value = ""

sh.Protect "1234"

MsgBox "Nytt våpen lagt til", vbInformation

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox3.Value = ""
Me.TextBox4.Value = ""
Me.TextBox5.Value = ""
Me.TextBox6.Value = ""
Me.TextBox7.Value = ""
Me.TextBox8.Value = ""
Me.TextBox9.Value = ""

End Sub
```

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: You need to adjust the code below `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("A:A"), Me.TextBox1.Value) > 0 Then`. You currently return a msgbox and exit the sub. What have your tried to adjust yourself?

Comment: The code is just a form to import values. That one works. I am looking for a user form that will search for and update the values that i write in to the excel sheet from this form. If you look at the topic i linked to you can see a code that i tried to implement in the search / update form, however it could not update values if the identifier was non-numeric. In sum, I am looking for a user form that can search and update values in the excel-sheet where i add values from the form in the code. Wish to use one sheet for adding data (the one I have) and one sheet for searching and updating.

Answer (score 0):

To update the data in a specific row you can use a procedure similar to the code below.  Pass it a row number and it will update the cells on that row - :  `Update 5` will update row 5.

```
Public Sub Update(RowNum As Long)
    With Sheet1 'Using the sheets Code Name (Sheet Name not in brackets in Project Explorer).
        .Cells(RowNum, 2) = "Some New Value in column B"
        .Cells(RowNum, 4) = "Some Other Value in column D"
        .Range(.Cells(RowNum, 5), .Cells(RowNum, 7)) = Array("A", 3, "Whatever") 'Update values in column E:G
    End With
End Sub
```

You need to find the row that your Serial number appears on.  Pass the function a serial number that exists in column 1 and it will return the row number, if it doesn't exist it will return 0: - `FindRow("R/16916")` will return 3 in your image.

```
Public Function FindRow(SearchString As String) As Long

    Dim tmpRng As Range

    With Sheet1.Columns(1)
        Set tmpRng = .Find(What:=SearchString, _
                           After:=.Cells(1), _
                           LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not tmpRng Is Nothing Then
            FindRow = tmpRng.Row
        Else
            'Row not found, return an illegal row number.
            FindRow = 0
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Stick it all together:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim lRow As Long

    'Use the FindRow function to return the row number of the searched item.
    lRow = FindRow("R/16916")

    If lRow > 0 Then
        'Update the data in that row.
        Update lRow
    End If

End Sub
```